# Expanding width of container in CSS

Tags: css, overflow, css-selectors

I have a list that contains n li element and the parent ul element has a max-height rule. What I want to to is expanding the width of ul when the li elements overflow the ul element.

Let's say I have 20 li elements each of 20px height and the max-height value is 100px. In this case the ul element must have 20/(100px/20px)=4 columns.

When I have a fixed width value, CSS automatically expands the height of ul but in fixed height I couldn't find any way to expand its width with respect to the number of li elements.

I tried nth-child selector with clear rule but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhm9f/

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS Part:

```
ul li {
    width:50px;
    background:#eee;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
div {
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}
ul {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid gray

}
ul li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background:red;
    clear:both
}
```

Is there any to do something like that in CSS?

Comment: +1 for a very interesting test case

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way this can be accomplished with just CSS.  For the sake of solving your issue, I was able to come up with a javascript/jQuery solution.

See the working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bBmbw/) demo.

*Play around with the `ul` `max-height` and `li` `height` CSS values in the demo to see how jQuery handles different values.  It's a pretty neat little solution.*

---

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>test 01</li>
    <li>test 02</li>
    <li>test 03</li>
    <li>test 04</li>
    <li>test 05</li>
    <li>test 06</li>
    <li>test 07</li>
    <li>test 08</li>
    <li>test 09</li>
    <li>test 10</li>
    <li>test 11</li>
    <li>test 12</li>
    <li>test 13</li>
    <li>test 14</li>
    <li>test 15</li>
    <li>test 16</li>
    <li>test 17</li>
    <li>test 18</li>
    <li>test 19</li>
    <li>test 20</li>
</ul>
```

---

### CSS

```
ul 
{
    max-height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
ul li 
{
    width:50px;
    height:20px;
    background:#eee;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

---

### jQuery

```
var $ul = $("ul");
    $listItems = $ul.find("li"),
    listItemCount = $listItems.length,
    listItemHeight = parseInt($listItems.css("height")),
    maxHeight = parseInt($ul.css("max-height")),
    numberOfRows = Math.floor(maxHeight / listItemHeight),
    numberOfColumns = Math.ceil(listItemCount / numberOfRows);

$ul.find("li:nth-child(" + numberOfColumns.toString() + "n+1)")
   .css
   ({ 
      "clear": "both", 
      "background": "red"
   });
```

Comment: I actually did in a way similar to yours but I'm looking for pure css solution. Thanks for the answer though.